# Monospaced font on Windows

Tags: fonts

I have Monaco font. The Ubuntu says that it is monospaced, but Windows XP doesn't. Is there anyway to tell Windows that it **is** monospaced(e.g. change some options with help of FontForge or whatever)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please choose a suitable username and feel free to stick around!

Comment: What form is the font in (TrueType, Postscript,...)? Maybe you could indicate where you downloaded it, so we can check it.

Comment: I downloaded it here : http://www.gringod.com/2006/11/01/new-version-of-monaco-font/

Answer (score 1):

From the [FontForge FAQ](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/faq.html#monospace):

> **How do I mark a font as monospaced?**
>   You don't. Just ensure that all the glyphs in the font have the same
>   width and then FontForge will automatically mark it as monospaced for
>   you. (If you mark it as monospaced incorrectly some rasterizers will
>   give strange results). If you want to set a font's panose values
>   yourself (**Element → Font Info → OS/2 → Panose**) then set the Proportion
>   field to Monospaced. This is necessary but not sufficient to mark the
>   font as a whole as monospaced. If you are unsure whether all the
>   glyphs in your font have the same advance width use **Element → Find
>   Problems → Random → Check Advance**.

This seems to work, so check it with your font file.

Comment: Nope. Mono fonts supporting Chinese, Japanese, and Korean have certain glyphs that are 'fullwidth', taking twice the width of ASCII characters. Yet, despite the non-uniform width, Windows recognizes them as monospace. What mechanics are used in this detection, and what can FontForge do to set it off?